# An specific timezone is not available on a RDS Aurora MySQL cluster

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, database, rds, mysql5.6

I have a database in RDS MySQL 5.7 instance and within the Parameters Groups I have defined the parameter "time_zone" as "America / Santiago", but now I want to migrate the database to an Aurora MySQL Serverless cluster (Running MySQL 5.6) but the timezone "America/Santiago" is not available within the "Allowed values".

What is appropriate in these cases so as not to have time_zone differences in the data?

[image: Parameter screenshot]

Comment: Run and store in UTC. Convert on the front-end. It'll save you an immense amount of grief in the long run.

Comment: I was thinking in that, I think I will do it that way.